# jquery ajax return values into html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need help with returning values from `jQuery/AJAX` to `html` form inside `index.php`

**index.php :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#display').ready(function () {
    var pageid = '<?php echo $_GET[\'ID\'] ;?>';
    var powiat = '<?php echo $row[\'powiat\'] ;?>'
    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to display.php
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'display.php?ID=' + pageid + '&powiat=' + powiat,
      dataType: 'html', //expect html to be returned                
      success: function (response) {
        $('#responsecontainer').html(response);
        //alert(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
(...)
echo "<form  action=\"save.php\" method=\"GET\">";
echo "<tr><td>IP</td><td><div id=\"responsecontainer\"></td></tr>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\">" ;
echo "</table></form>
```

**display.php file contains:**

```
$disp_result_2 = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM swittche_ip WHERE powiat LIKE '%$disp_powiat%' AND ip NOT IN ( SELECT ip FROM switche )" )or die(mysql_error());
while($disp_row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($disp_result_2)){
    echo "<option value=\"".$disp_row_1['ip']."\">".$disp_row_1['ip']</option>";
}
```

In return I have filed `html` as expected but when I try submit form filed by `jquery/ajax` I have error

> Notice: Undefined index: ip.

How can I handle with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Your PHP has syntax errors.  Where specifically is this error thrown?  Surely this code is generating other errors as well?

Comment: your question aside, Why are you still using `mysql_*`?

Comment: Are you mixing JS and PHP? If your `echo` is PHP then it should be `echo '';` adding the double quotes like this `echo "";` is gonna give you an error the way you're doing the echo.

Comment: Ok . I paste fragments of code. Rest is relevant. I normally don't use mysql_ but  i try to modify old code. Syntax what you see dont give me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your code when you are printing the `option`.

Updated code is as below.

```
     $disp_result_2 = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM swittche_ip WHERE powiat LIKE '%$disp_powiat%' AND ip NOT IN ( SELECT ip FROM switche )" )or die(mysql_error());
        while($disp_row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($disp_result_2)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $disp_row_1['ip'];?>" ><?php echo $disp_row_1['ip'];?></option>
            <?php }
```